# Athena query executed through boto3 python client gives smaller result compared to query executed through AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to execute a very simple query through Athena.

Query: `select * from information_schema.tables`

When I execute the query using the boto3 client with the following code:

```
...

def run_query(query_string):
    query_execution_context = {"Catalog": "awsdatacatalog", "Database": "information_schema"}
    response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query_string, QueryExecutionContext=query_execution_context, WorkGroup="primary"
    )
    return response

query_string_get_tables = "select * from information_schema.tables"
response = run_query(query_string_get_tables)
```

I get back a result of 9 rows in 0.6s.

When I then go to the AWS console and rerun the same query I get back a result of 500 rows in 6s.

The result from the AWS console is correct. How can I get the same result using the boto3 client?

EDIT:
I downloaded the query history and compared the query string. As you can see they are exactly the same. I also removed the QueryExecutionContext in the boto3 client call but this doesn't change anything. Besides, I tried all combinations of single/double quotes.

Query history:

```
37b72ac5-3223-496f-8293-79eab8a661a0,select * from information_schema.tables,2022-12-02T18:23:09.738-08:00,SUCCEEDED,6.503 sec,39.01 KB,Athena engine version 2,'-

9d3a274a-8109-4988-aaf8-bba9c8733208,select * from information_schema.tables,2022-12-02T18:14:11.385-08:00,SUCCEEDED,520 ms,0.67 KB,Athena engine version 2,'-
```

Comment: `start_query_execution` is only starting the query. You should use the `get_query_results` to get the results.

Comment: Consider to youse https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/ or https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ 
both libraries should retrieve query result for you from s3, and give that back as in memory python result.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments using boto3 needs some efforts to `start_query_execution`, wait for its completion, and then `get_query_results` (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_results).

To make your life easier, you can use the open-source library AWSWrangler or [AWS-SDK-Pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). With this library to can get the results in a blocking manner:

```
# Retrieving the data from Amazon Athena
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table", database="my_db")
```